# How to RemoveText Before Fle Extension

Tags: javascript

I want to remove 3 characters before file extension of an image, for example this path of image.

from this `<img src="www.example.com/img/image123.jpg">`
to this `<img src="www.example.com/img/image.jpg">`

How to do that in javascript?

Comment: What should be removed from the file `archive.tar.gz`?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you want to remove only numeric parts? Or do you have to specify a string `partToRemove = '123'` and in each file you are scanning, if present that part, you want to remove it?

Comment: I've already edited my post, sorry bout that

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not specific enough, I did this:

```
// Your array of files
const files = [ 'image123.jpg', 'test.jpg', 'file.txt', 'docum123ents.doc' ];
// The part you want to remove from each file you are going to scan
const partToRemove = '123';
// New array with new files name
let newFiles = [];

console.log(files);

// For each file in files
newFiles = files.map(element => {
    // if element includes the part you want to remove
    if (element.includes(partToRemove)) {
        // replace that part with an empty string and return the element
        return element.replace(partToRemove, '');
    } else {
        // return the element, it's already without 'partToRemove'
        return element;
    }
});

console.log('------');
console.log(newFiles);
```

OUTPUT:

```
[ 'image123.jpg', 'test.jpg', 'file.txt', 'docum123ents.doc' ]
------
[ 'image.jpg', 'test.jpg', 'file.txt', 'documents.doc' ]
```

Comment: OP didn't mentioned about removing numeric part any where.

Comment: @MaheerAli the question is not specific. So this is what I understand from a question like this. If the question will be edited and this is not what he wants I will delete this answer.

Comment: @JoKeRxbLaCk sorry I misunderstood. +1

Comment: The question needs more clarity, are you trying to remove any number of any length at the end of the filename or its always going to be 123 or the length of number at the end of the filename would always be 3 ? Provide more details to get the help you need.